# Alt+tab key not working in NX client for linux

Tags: ubuntu, nx

I am using NX clinet-3.5.0-7 version running on ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch between different terminals on my NX client but I am unable to do so. When ever I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it switches the different panels open on my Ubuntu 12.04 instead. I tried to follow [this link](http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR04C00174) but that didn't help as there is no "Grab the keyboard when the client has focus" option in Advance Tab.

I also tried [link](http://www.edwardotis.net/tech/?p=224) but nothing comes out.

Seeking suggestions.

Comment: You could try asking this on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 3):

After experiencing a similar problem I found a workaround. I hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F` in the NX session to enter full-screen mode and use `Alt`+`Tab` to switch between the session windows. When I want to `Alt`+`Tab` out of the NX client, I hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F` first to exit full-screen mode.